# Link php not showing correctly

Tags: php

Iam creating a shout in my shoutbox like this:

```
$text = "[color=Lime][b]Um novo torrent foi criado no ".$GLOBALS["SITENAME"]." @ [url=details.php?id=".$id."] $torrent [/url] [/color] pelo membro [url=member-details.php?id=".$CURUSER[id]."] ".$CURUSER[username]." [/url].[/b]";
```

It works excpet for the link to the user: [url=member-details.php?id=".$CURUSER[id]."]

it shows: htttp://........../member-details.php?id=\'2\'

instead of htttp://........../member-details.php?id=2

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put

```
$CURUSER[id] = stripslashes($CURUSER[id]);
```

before that line.

also, there are only 2 t's in http

Comment: Thank you casts, it worked. the extra t is i cannot put here links... thank you friend.